# Using input_attrs() Multiple Times Within One Customizer Control

Tags: functions, input

**Using input_attrs() Multiple Times Within One Customizer Control**.

I want to be able to use the function `input_attrs()`
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_control/input_attrs/

With this type of code `$this->input_attrs()` And I want to be able to use the function multiple times...

Example 1:

`<input type="text" value="blah1" <?php $this->input_attrs($1); ?>>`

`<input type="text" value="blah2" <?php $this->input_attrs($2); ?>>`

The first example is not correct php. Do you know how to write this correctly?

Example 2:

`<input type="text" value="blah1" <?php $this->input_attrs(); ?>>`

`<input type="text" value="blah2" <?php $this->input_attrs_2(); ?>>`

If I do end up using a `input_attrs_2()` Do I also need my own function `get_input_attrs_2()` ?

Comment: If you mean [this `input_attrs()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_control/input_attrs/), it doesn't take any arguments (your `$1` ad `$2` won't work). Please [edit your question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/posts/413694/edit) to show us more of your code, and explain what you're trying to accomplish (and what's going wrong).

Comment: is this a customizer question? Can you edit your question to add more context? It kind of jumps straight into it without any explanation of what you're trying to do or why

Comment: This is a WordPress forum. There is only 1 input_attrs() function so I assumed you know what the line input_attrs() meant. Sorry I added the link to the exact function.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to call the input_attrs() method directly. Instead, rely on the [add_control()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_manager/add_control/) method of the wordpress customizer object to generate the html inputs for your customizer settings. The `add_control()` method takes as its second argument an array of properties that allows you to set the label for the input, the section of the customizer where the input will be found, the type of input (text, checkbox, <select>, etc.), and more. A complete list of properties you can set via the second argument of add_control() can be found [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_customize_control/__construct/). One of them is `input_attrs`. If you pass this property an array of name/value pairs, `add_control()` will include them as custom attributes and values on the html inputs it generates.

As a loose example of what this might look like when you put it all together:

```
add_action( 'customize_register', 'mytheme_customize_register');

function mytheme_customize_register( $wp_customize ) {
   
    $wp_customize->add_setting( 'mytheme_mysetting', array(
        'default' => '',
        'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field'
    ) );
    
    $wp_customize->add_control( 'mytheme_mysetting', array(
        'label' => __( 'My website user of the month', 'mytheme-textdomain' ),
        'type' => 'text',
        'section' => 'mysection',
        'input_attrs' => array(
          'my-custom-attribute-name' => 'my custom attribute value',
          'foo' => 'bar'
        )
    ));
}
```

Comment: I'm calling input_attrs directly. Please delete your answer, it does not answer the question at all. I am only working on input_attrs specifically. Nothing else. I do not need help with writing controls.

Comment: My question is very efficient and good and should be answered more specifically.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone reads my question and wants an answer. To reproduce `input_attrs()` as many times as you want in a crude way all you need to do is define a variable each time in the class. For example `public $inputattrs2` and then you are able to use the code `echo esc_attr($this->inputattrs2);` or `echo $this->inputattrs2;` along with your html in your class control and the add_control. This works for anything including text descriptions or html attributes.